# Catch(error) on dispatched method in store not working in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js

**I am working on login of a vue 3 app**, both the login and registration work fine, but i still need to throw send back a meaningful response to user if login in credentials are rejected by the back-end, i have tried every possible means to log the rejection response from server to console but to no avail, the login is fine when credential is correct, **but the console just stay mute when incorrect credential is entered**

this is my login.vue

```
import store from "../store"
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { ref } from "vue";

const router = useRouter()
const user = { email: '', password: '', remember : false }
let errorMsg = ref('');

async function login(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    await store.dispatch('login', user)
    .then(()=> {
         router.push({
            name: 'Dashboard'
         })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    errorMsg = err.response.data.error
    console.log(err)
    })
}
```

and this is my vuex store

```
    import {createStore} from 'vuex'
    import axiosClient from "../axios";
    
    const store = createStore({
        state: {
            user: {
                data: {},
                token: sessionStorage.getItem('TOKEN')
            }
        },
        getters: {},
        setters: {},
        actions: { 
            register({commit}, user) {
                return axiosClient.post('/register', user)
                .then(({data}) => {
                   commit('setUser', data);
                   return data;
                })
            },
    
            login({commit}, user) {
               return axiosClient.post('/login', user)
               .then(({data}) => {
                  commit('setUser', data);
                  return data;
               })
            },
        },
        mutations: {
           logout: state => {
            state.user.data = {};
            state.user.token = null;
           },
           setUser: (state, userData)=> {
            state.user.token = userData.token;
            state.user.data = userData.user;
            sessionStorage.setItem('TOKEN', userData.token)
           }
        },
        modules: {}
    })
    export default store;
```

And here is my axios js file

```
import axios  from "axios";
import store from "./store";

const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api'
})

axiosClient.interceptors.request.use(config=> {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${store.state.user.token}`
    return config;
})

export default axiosClient;
```

Response from backend as seen from Network Tab

***{"error":"The provided credentials are incorrect","0":422}***

Comment: It's unknown what's server response. In case it's really an error (e.g. 403) I don't see how this may work as you described. The code looks ok and should behave correctly. The only problem is `errorMsg = err.response.data.error`. It's a mistake to reassign ref vars, and err.response.data.error is not guaranteed to exist. There should be errors in console any way if it fails.

Comment: @EstusFlask **the server response is known**, i can see it from the network tab, : it is the exact rejection message i set myself from my laravel back-end, with a status code of 422, could my status code be the reason my front-end can't get anything ?

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough info, it's known to you, but not anybody else. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . 422 causes Axios to fail and results in rejected promise and so .catch is triggered -  unless there's axios interceptor that you didn't show. The only problem is what I explained above. Did you check errors in console and fixed this line? In case the problem persists, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  that can reproduce it

Comment: @EstusFlask  i think it may be necessary that i include the axios client file, i have an interceptor there for passing the user security token with the requests, and the question has been updated to include it

Comment: No, shouldn't affect this, unless you have *response* interceptors

Comment: Looks to me like you're not throwing an error from backend. You're returning some random JSON object and you expect axios to treat it as an error. Axios will treat it as a valid response: `{data: {"error":"The provided credentials are incorrect","0":422}, status: 200}`. Correct me if I'm wrong. If I'm not wrong, all you need to do is throw an error from backend and axios will interpret it correctly. Read [Reporting exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#reporting-exceptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking through my `controller` in my `Laravel` project, I discovered that I did not set the status code for the response properly.

#### Incorrect code:

```
    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
        return response([
            'error'=> 'The provided credentials are incorrect',
            422
        ]);
    }
```

#### Corrected code:

```
    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
        return response([
            'error'=> 'The provided credentials are incorrect',
        ], 422);
    }
```

`Axios` does not treat the response received as a rejection; which needs to get its `catch` triggered.

Therefore my `console.log` that I had in my `try/catch` does not run at all.

I'm very happy we got this solved, big thanks to every one.